# Necessary and sufficient condition on the cardinal number of quotient set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, cardinals

I'm studying for an exam, and I have found question that I'm not sure about how to solve it. The question is: Let A be finite set. Let R be equivalence relation on A.

1.Write necessary and sufficient condition on the cardinal number of quotient set so R will be equality relation (equality relation is the relation R: xRy iff x=y.

2.Is the necessary and sufficient condition from (1.) true for infinite set A?

My solution for 1 is:

|A/R| = |A| **iff** R is the equality relation.

I think its true
because the number of all equivalence classes equal to the the number of elements in A.

For example A = {1,2,3}

[1]R = {1}

[2]R = {2}

[3]R = {3}

My solution for 2 is:

Yes, The cardinal of A/R is still equal to the cardinal of A.

I would like to know where my mistakes are.
Tell me please if the absence of Latex notations is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution to 1) is correct. However for an infinite set the condition is necessary but not sufficient. For example, consider the set of integers under an equivalence relation where all the equivalence classes are finite sets. (Thanks to Andreas Blass for correction.)

Comment: You don't want "equivalent mod 2" since its quotient has size 2. But there are plenty of examples for $\mathbb Z$; you could just identify one pair of distinct elements.

Comment: Very true @Andreas  Blass! Careless mistake. I shall edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, But in did fully understood in which case this condition is not sufficient.
Maybe it's the case of rational numbers?
when 2/4 equal to 1/2, but its does not adds new equivalence class?

Comment: It's simply that, although the equivalence relation is not equality, both A and A\R have the same cardinality. A in this case is the set of integers and A\R is the set of equivalence classes under R. Both sets are countably infinite.